# How to prompt user to enable location services on receiving notification

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in which location updates turn on when a notification is received. but if a user disable his/her location services then how can i prompt the user to enable location services while my app is in background.

Comment: Post a local notification asking them to enable location?

Comment: I am using FCM that is sent by my server.

Comment: Yes, but you have a delegate method that fires when you receive the message. You can check for location access and post a local notification asking the user to turn it back on. You won't be able to update their location in response to that push message though.

Comment: yeah But i have to start location updates without user interaction. In other word i have to turn on location updates silently.

Comment: Your app will need to ask for "always" location permission when the user first runs it. If they have revoked this permission or turned location services off then all you can do is ask them to go to settings and grant permission.

Comment: the scenario in my case is i have installed the app and authenticate from user to allow location updates "always" and at this time the location services of Iphone are enabled. but after this user disable the location services of phone and my push notification of starting location updates is received. at this time what can i do?

Comment: As I said, all you can do is show a local notification asking the user to turn location back on. If they don't, they don't. The user always has control over the use of their location.

Comment: ok. 
if i start location updates and user location services are disabled. But after some time user enable his/her location services then can i get location updates at that time and send it to my server?